# SQL Combine dates to a single date

Tags: mysql

i have the following tables:

table1: matricula, date, cost_One;

table2: matricula, date, cost_Two;

table3: matricula, date, cost_Three.

What I'm trying to query is a simple sum of the costs mentioned, grouped by matricula and date, that returns one result per month, and it must be able to retrieve a result if there aren't records present in all tables, but at least one of the tables has. or all of them or just two.

If someone can exemplify with code would be great since I've tried already a lot and couldn't make it.

Comment: UNION ALL then aggregate need more help read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, but isnt UNION ALL or union a bad practice in terms of query large datasets? i was trying coalesce didnt work, should i progress with trying union all?

Comment: There a a number of ways to solve this but you haven't provided enough information to supply a more optimal solution , and what do you mean by large datasets? Best practice is try it if too slow try something else.

Comment: ill try with union all and see if it shows all records, and can do the query fast, because i was doing with coalesce and couldnt retrieve all records, im trying different way, to get the query up and running, thanks for sharing idea

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` if you don't want `UNION`